# Можно ли использовать очищенную память повторно в С?

Tags: c

Можно ли создать для примера динамический массив(с функцией malloc), заполнить его произвольными значениями, а после очистки(free) снова заполнить?

Comment: `free` - это не очистка, а освобождение ранее выделенной памяти. Заново заполнить его произвольными значениями можно до вызова `free`.

Comment: "Съесть-то он съест, да кто ж ему даст?" (с) Можете заполнить, но получится то, что называется UB (неопределенное поведение)/